# strange objective C bug, properties not case sensitive?

Tags: objective-c

I have two properties "M" and "m", not the best coding style I know but bear with me. Assignment to these properties in the init method does not function properly. Here's the code in it's entirety:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int M;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int m;
- (id)initWithM:(int)M m:(int)m;
@end

@implementation Foo

- (id)initWithM:(int)M m:(int)m {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.M = M;
        printf("M = %d %d\n", M, self.M);
        self.m = m;
        printf("M = %d %d\n", M, self.M);
        printf("m = %d %d\n", m, self.m);
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    Foo *f = [[Foo alloc] initWithM:2 m:1];
}
@end
```

And here is the output from the printf's:

```
M = 2 2
M = 2 1
m = 1 0
```

If I change "M" to "BAR" and "m" to "bar" it works as I would expect. Is there an explanation for this other than being a compiler bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using? Your code doesn't compile in Xcode 4.6. `main.m:21:9: Synthesized properties 'M' and 'm' both claim setter 'setM:' - use of this setter will cause unexpected behavior'

Comment: Xcode 4.4.1 . I guess they caught this after my version.

Comment: @CharlieBurns You missed the site then. Downvoting out of disagreement is accepted on Meta, but not on SO (go read the FAQ). If you disagree, leave a comment, or add another answer explaining what should have been done in your opinion. You should only and ever downvote if the answer is techinically wrong (which it certainly wasn't), or if it is spam (which it wasn't either).

Comment: @CharlieBurns Thanks. I suggest we clean up all of these comments then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@property int M;
@property int m;
```

both create

```
- (void)setM:(int)
```

If you really wanted to have both an `m` and an `M` property (which you definitely shouldn't) you can use

```
@property int M;
@property (setter = setLowerCaseM:, getter = lowerCaseM)int m;
```

Comment: Yep, that explains it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure they both use the same getter in this situation?